# Обращение к кнопке по селектору

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка:

```
<button class="button_view">HI</button>
```

Пытаюсь к ней обратиться:

```
$(".button_view").on('click', function() {}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> $ is not defined
>   Почему?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы что-то происходило по нажатии кнопки? Или получить название кнопки?

Comment: происходило при нажатии кнопки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> // Подключаем библиотеку jquery<br>
</script>
<button class="button_view">HI</button>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(".button_view").on('click', function() { // Сам код
        alert("Hello Alex, I`m clicked");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: вроде все так же

Comment: @Александр, скопируйте, вставьте в файл. Не может не работать. Надо отметить, что подключение jquery должно происходить в до выполнения скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите использовать функции jQuery ($) - подключите его.
А вообще, зачастую через данный символ регистрируют глобальные переменные.

jQuery:

```js
$(".button_view").on('click', function() {
  alert('click')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button_view">HI</button>
```

Чистый Javascript:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button_view')
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('click')
})
```

```html
<button class="button_view">HI</button>
```

Comment: у меня вроде все так же. В чем проблема?

Comment: может порядок подключения скриптов неверный, проверьте чтобы jquery подключился до вашего скрипта